# WriteUTF and ReadUTF, how can i write a string and get a short exception in another side?

Tags: java, android, sockets, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

Basically i'm doing a socket connection between two sides. A Java server and a Android client. I'm converting objects to String Json  using Gson library , and sending them through method WriteUTF from Android client. But when i try to get response in Java server i get a "java.io.EOFException at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)". How, if i didn't used this method (readUnsignedShort) or even didn't send any Short ? Here comes the codes.

Writing from Android client:

```
 try {
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (s3.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s3.getOutputStream());

                ap = (ArrayList<Produto>) InternalStorage.readObject(getBaseContext(),"pedido");

                 for(int i=0;i<ap.size()&& ap.size()>0;i++){

                        Produto p = new Produto("", "", 0f, "", "", 0);
                        p = ap.get(i);
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String json = gson.toJson(p);
                        out.writeUTF(json);
                        out.flush();

                    }
```

And Reading from Java server:

```
try {
        // Get input from the client
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (server.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());


        while((line = in.readUTF()) != null) {
            boolean error = false;

            String json = line;
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Produto p2 = gson.fromJson(json, Produto.class);
            c = dbDelegate.getCommandByNumber(p2.getMesa());
            p = dbDelegate.getProductByName(p2.getNome());
            if(c!=null && p!=null){
                error = false;
            inCommand.setCommand(c);
            inCommand.setDateAndTime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            inCommand.setProduct(p);
            inCommand.setLogin(FishingBoardFrameCashRegister.getInstance().getLogin());
            inCommand.setQuantity(p2.getQuantidade());
            inCommand.setPrice(String.valueOf((p2.getValor()*p2.getQuantidade())));
            inCommand.setObs(p2.getObs());
            inCommand.setProductName(p.getName());
            inCommand.setType(Product.ALL);
            inCommand.setSession(0);
            inCommand.setCommandSession(c.getSession());
            if(dbDelegate.insertProductInCommand(inCommand) == DbDelegate.CASH_CLOSED){
                error = true;
            }
            FishingBoardFrameCashRegister.getInstance().updateTable();
            }else{
                error = true;
            }
```

The log may help too:

```
trueIOException on socket listen: java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at com.keymax.server.doComms3.run(Server3.java:71)
```

Server3.java:71 is this line in server code:  while((line = in.readUTF()) != null) {

Answer (score 0):

I think the `EOFException` is expected here, because that's what you will get if you call `readUTF` and there is no data left.

I would fix this by using `writeInt` before the loop to write out how many strings are about to be written, and then `readInt` on the other end, so that you don't call `readUTF` more times than the number of strings actually available in the stream.

`writeUTF` probably writes the length of the string and then the data in the string, which explains why `readUnsignedShort` is the one getting the `EOFException`.

Comment: Got the point. Excelent solution ! I'll try it, than i post here my results. Thanks !